# jQuery | Input name with multiple dimensional array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am building a plugin for the WordPress, and I have a screen that need to manipulate the data of multiple dimensional array names. More specific, I have the input elements like the following:

```
<div class="settingsContainer">
    <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[1][title]" value="Initial fare">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[1][rate]" value="2.25">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[1][description]" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[1][whenType]" value="always">
</div>
<div class="settingsContainer">
    <input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][title]" value="Initial fare II">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][rate]" value="2.25">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][description]" value="Hello">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][weekday][]" value="Mo">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][weekday][]" value="We">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][weekday][]" value="Th">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][startHour]" value="00:02">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][endHour]" value="23:56">
    <input type="hidden" name="initialFare[2][whenType]" value="dayshours">
</div>
```

Now, the problem is, how to iterate over the weekdays of the second settingsContainer, and in general, how can I write my selectors for multiple dimensional array names. Is there any good tutorial for writing name selectors ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this selector :

```
$('input[name="initialFare[2][weekday][]"]')
```

See the [documentation on jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: This will return an array with all the records related to ?

Comment: What do you mean by record ? This will let you iterate over the three elements having this name.

Comment: I mean with any input field that contain this name. I suppose yes eh ?